# How to prevent errors when removing tables in the database used in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

When I remove tables used in my Azure database (of course after removing the entities), I just use DROP TABLE TABLENAME. This has a bad effect. When I run the mobile service by just starting the browser, I get an Error 500 when I add a new record (of an existing table of course) with my TableControllers. Apparently, I did something wrong. It can be "solved" by creating a completely new database and use this one in my mobile service. The Seed method ensures that the right tables exist (and only the right tables) and everything works fine.

What is the best way (to prevent errors) when removing tables in a database used in Azure Mobile Services. Creating a completely new database seems to be a bit overdone and unneeded.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the tables after removing the entities? The code is written to use that table and if you drop the table, how are you expecting it to work

Comment: I do not need the table anymore. Therefore, I remove the table, the Entity (I mean the Entity class) and all code that uses it. If I update a record of a completely different table, I get an error. This can be prevented by creating a completely new database (which seems overdone). All I want to know is what to do when I do not need a table anymore. Simple DROP TABLE TABLENAME causes issues as described. Even when updating a completely other table, I get an error.

Comment: How I expect things to work is: 1. not get an error. 2. Be able to add records to other tables. As I said, things work but only if I create a new database (which is overdone).

Comment: That table you dropped might be linked to other tables, and those association might still be there in the front end, when you set it up. You did remove the table from the database, but not the associations....

Comment: Good point. But that is not the case. I do not use secondary keys.

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct is that it's an issue with Entity Framework. It doesn't generally play nicely with people touching the database. If you looked through your log, you'd probably see Entity Framework issues.

Take a look at this Azure Doc: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/

It discusses how to enable code first migrations - I won't elaborate here because there are a couple of steps.

Essentially, the problem is that Entity Framework takes a number of dependencies and when those dependencies change, it just falls over on itself. Let me know if that doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me  understanding it and I did not know this article. I'll study the article and let you know wether it helps me solving the problems.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me solving the problem. I should not manually remove tables if I do not need them. That is the big lesson.